# Capybara Rspec Matcher assert tbody is empty

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a webpage where you have a table element containing data. You can search / filter this data.  When a search is invalid i.e no record matches your criteria, the table renders blank.

HTML will look like this:

```
<tbody></tbody>
```

I am writing a test to assert that the tbody element is indeed empty or blank.  I was using `expect(find('tbody')).to have_text ''`

I'm not too happy with this as it also passes when there is text with any whitespace.

Is there a better way to assert this?

EDIT:

I have run this successfully >

```
expect(find('table > tbody', visible: false)).not_to have_css('td')
```

I am still open to any better solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the `tbody` is empty by verifying it has no children with

```
expect(find('tbody')).to have_no_css('*')
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Works well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a has_no_content matcher in Capybara.

```
expect(find('tbody').has_no_content?).to be true
```

or

```
expect(find('tbody')).to have_no_content
```

https://devhints.io/capybara